# Why I'm Getting (/dev/unrecognised disk label) (udisks-error quark, 0)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I'm using WD240G(240GB)(T0707A0) 240 GB SSD on my PC,

Firstly I was trying to install windows 10 on my SSD,

But it says unable to format Disk in Windows 10 setup,
Then I've tried to install ubuntu on my SSD but there was only my HDD SAMSUNG SP2504C (VT100-50) 250 Hard Disk and SSD Was not showing?

I have installed Ubuntu in my HDD But then it says that DISK IS LIKELY TO FAIL SOON (48° C / 118° F),

And when I try to Delete and Format it says error deleting partition /dev/sda1 failed to read a partition table on device '/dev/sda'
[image: Image of Error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The partition table (aka "disk label") on that disk is unrecognizable. It's either missing or corrupted.

Why it could be missing:

- It's typical for brand new disks
- Wiped (or partially wiped) disks don't have one
- The filesystem is created on the entire disk, without partitioning - this is unusual but sometimes makes sense, especially with ZFS
- The drive may be a part of a RAID array and you need the rest of the array + RAID software/hardware to get it to work

In all of these cases you can create a new partition table and carry on. *This will cause data loss if there was any data on the disk.*

Why the partition table could be corrupted:

## This disk is failing!

Can you see the warning in red all caps?

> DISK IS LIKELY TO FAIL SOON

Disk's auto-diagnostics show that this disk is dying. The partition table probably got corrupted due to this. Therefore you shouldn't use this disk to store anything of value. It can stop working anytime.

Comment: Thank you Gronostaj for your answer, Actually, I have a Warranty for 2 years of this SSD can I replace this SSD with my warranty?

Comment: @iftiben10 Oh, I thought it's the HDD, sorry. You probably can. Let''s take a look at the SMART attributes. You can view them using the _Disks_ window's menu.